# Enabling and disabling abbrev globally and by major-mode

Tags: abbrev

Have noticed that `abbrev-mode` only works for the current buffer.  Thus using the following configuration does not enable abbrev-mode when I load an `org-mode` file.

```
(require 'toro)
(toro-abbrev)
```

Here is the file that provides the `toro-abbrev` feature.

```
(defconst tablet2 
   '( ("is" "s")      ("it" "t")       ("know" "no")
      ("like" "lk")   ("little" "ll")  ("more" "mo")

(defun toro-abbrev ()
  "Enables words to be expanded as one types."
  (interactive)
  (abbrev-mode 1)
  (kill-all-abbrevs)
  (define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table tablet2))

(provide 'toro)
```

How could I turn on `abbrev-mode` globally or for buffers with a specific major mode?

Comment: I don't know if there is a global minor mode for `abbrev` but for the major-mode part of the question (which I added - you are welcome!), you use the major-mode hook.

Comment: So I can do `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'abbrev-mode)`.  But then how can I disable?

Comment: Or just do `(M-x abbrev-mode)`?

Comment: All of your questions are answered here, I believe: [Abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html).

Comment: Maybe, but there are no examples as usual.  Simply commands that never end.

Comment: I would do `(defun turn-on-abbrev-mode () (abbrev-mode 1))` and `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'turn-on-abbrev-mode)`: I find it easier to read. As for disabling, when would you want to do that? There is a natural time to enable: when the buffer is created. The only  natural time  to disable I can think of is when the buffer is killed, but then it doesn't matter whether you disable or not. If the user wants to disable it at some point, they can do `C--  M-x abbrev-mode` - but it's very much a user choice, so Emacs cannot do anything about that: it cannot guess when a user might want to disable it.

Comment: BTW, if you want examples, you probably should read a textbook on Lisp, not the Emacs and Emacs Lisp reference manuals (at least not exclusively). See if you can borrow "The Little Lisper" from a library near you: it's chock-full of examples (in fact, everything is explained through examples). It may not be your cup of tea (tastes vary), hence the suggestion to borrow it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a bit late to the party.

To enable abbrev-mode globally just use `(setq-default abbrev-mode t)`

As Dilna already pointed out, to enable for major modes use `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'abbrev-mode)`

If you want to enable for multiple major modes, you can do:

```
(dolist (hook '(erc-mode-hook
                emacs-lisp-mode-hook
                text-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook #'abbrev-mode))
```

This knowledge was shamelessly stolen from JohnHunter who fantastically explains usage of abbrev on this [emacswiki site](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode).